# Firestore rule works in playground but not from external request

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an Android (Kotlin) application (min SDK version 26) that is using Google Firebase. As a part of this in particular, I am using Firestore. I have a rule that works in the rules playground but not from within my application and I cannot for the life of me understand why.

Here is the rule in question:

```
match /events/{eventId}
    allow delete, update: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/organisations/$(resource.data.organisationId)).data.access[request.auth.uid] == 'admin'
}
```

And here is the calling code:

```
db.collection("events").document(event.id)
    .delete()
    .addOnSuccessListener { _ ->

    }
    .addOnFailureListener { deleteResult ->
        println("-----> FAIL DELETE EVENT: $deleteResult")
    }
```

As you may be able to tell from the rule, permissions for the event are determined by a users' role in an event's parent organisation. In this instance I'm using the same user in the rules playground and from within the application, so there definitely isn't an actual permissions problem. I have a feeling that this issue has something to do with *"rules are not filters"* but I'm not really sure what to change...

Thanks

UPDATED to include screenshots of the database and UIDs below:

Below shows how I retrieve all events for a specific `organisationId` and loop over those to delete. Before deleting I print the users' `auth.uid`, the `eventId` and the `organisationId`.

```
db.collection("events")
    .whereEqualTo("organisationId", selectedOrganisationId)
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        for (event in result) {
            println("------ USER UID: ${currentUser?.uid}, EVENT ID: ${event.id} , ORG ID: ${event.get("organisationId")}")
            db.collection("events").document(event.id)
                .delete()
                .addOnSuccessListener { _ ->

                }
                .addOnFailureListener { deleteResult ->
                    println("-----> FAIL DELETE EVENT: $deleteResult")
                }
        }
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { result ->
        println("-----> FAIL GET EVENTS TO DELETE: $result")
    }
```

Below shows the output of the `println` containing the ids:

> I/System.out: ------ USER UID: lCagHz9IFSUoGp6eBhrr70HgUOp2, EVENT ID: gkf7FRq0gP0wHiCqhTVE , ORG ID: Wh1YkTmWptuDtaMKb2k6

And below this is the `FAIL DELETE EVENT` error:

> I/System.out: -----> FAIL DELETE EVENT: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Here are some screenshots of the Firestore database that show the ids in question existing, and the structure:
[image: Organisations]
[image: Event]

Another update:
Just a quick aside to mention that, if I modify the rule to `allow delete, update: if true`, the correct event(s) get deleted. So I'm absolutely definitely attempting to delete the correct documents.

Comment: Please edit your question to include all data that relevant. For example: 1) log the UID right before deleting the document, and include the updated code and output in your question, 2) log the `organisationId` field of the document right before the delete, and include the updated code and output in your question, 3) include a screenshot showing that the relevant document/data exists in `organisations` in your question.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, I've updated the question as per your suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for that. Now I can try to replay what the rules engine will do and see what happens. The first thing I'm wondering is whether this `data.access[request.auth.uid]` works. Can you do a simple `exists` in the document first to see if that works? Something like `if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/organisations/$(resource.data.organisationId))`. If that works, can you try making the UID a top-level field in the organization doc? So then you can test `if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/organisations/$(resource.data.organisationId)).data[request.auth.uid] == 'admin'`.

Comment: These are just steps to troubleshoot btw. It's not meant as a solution yet, but merely trying to get us to closer to the cause of the problem.

Comment: So I'm still getting a `PERMISSION_DENIED` with the rule: `if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/organisations/$(resource.data.organisationId))`. Again, the rule allows the operation from within the playground. Double checking ids again within my code, we're still pointing at the correct resource.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Just an FYI, a friend of mine put together a test program in Node and also gets a permission denied. So I'm very sure that it's just a misunderstanding of the limitations of the rules system as opposed to my code in particular...

Comment: Any update here? I'd love to hear if you were able to reproduce the working approach that I tried and showed in my answer below, or if you had any other findings on your own problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I haven't had a chance to look at this over the weekend. A friend of mine has since replicated this project exactly and has no issues - as far as we are aware everything is identical... Really not sure where to look further on this one! What could be a reason for the rule to work in the playground but not from an external request?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Solved this now. Thank you for your time and effort. It is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried to reproduce, but everything works as I'd expect it for me. I'll share what I've done, just so that you can see if there's anything different from what you did.

1. My root is `/61272476`, just because I use the same project for many more tests.
2. The rules I created for it are:

   ```
   match /61272476/{doc=**} {
       match /events/{eventId} {
           allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/61272476/README/organisations/$(resource.data.organisationId)).data.access[request.auth.uid] == 'admin'
       }
   }
   ```

   You'll note I made it a `read` rule, just so that it's easier to test.
3. The organization document looks like this:

   [image]
4. The event document that I tested with:

   [image]
5. And finally: the code that I tested with:

   ```
   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
     if (!user) {
       console.log("Signing in...");
       firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
     }
     else {
       console.log("Signed in user "+user.uid);
       var db = firebase.firestore();
       var ref = db.doc("61272476/README/events/event1").get().then(function(doc) {
         console.log("Got document", doc.data());
       }).catch(function(error) {
         console.error(error);
       });
     }
   });
   ```

You can also find the code in running form here: https://jsbin.com/rotefez/edit?js,console

When I remove the UID from the `access` field in the org, the read gets rejected. When I add it back, the read is allowed again.

At this point I have no idea how your case is different. I event tested if I was able to delete the document when I grant `delete` permission, and that worked as expected too.

At this point the best I can recommend is that your try to reproduce this on another project, similar to what I did here.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this. I'm in the process now of recreating the project so I will report back with my findings!

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to figure this out. I imagine this would have been a quick fix for @FrankvanPuffelen if I'd included the code that runs just after the events delete.

The Kotlin Firestore API is asynchronous. Directly after deleting all events associated to an organisation, but code calls a delete on the organisation itself; this is so that, when deleting an organisation, we delete all documents that would reference the organisation.

What was happening is that the events delete *and* the organisations delete were being called at pretty much the same time. The organisations delete would complete before apparently even the first events delete (likely because the events rules contain extra requests to the organisations collection). This would mean that, by the time the query on the organisation permissions from the events rule is executed, the organisation no longer exists, thus the request fails and we no longer have permission to delete the event.

Comment: Good to hear that you figured it out! This indeed would've been easier to spot if you'd included the fact/code that the organization is also being deleted in your question. This is why it's so important that you construct an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it will get you to the root of the problem a lot quicker. But still: this problem is solved, let's move on to the next one. :-)